# the security token could not be authenticated when trying to authenticate to adfs 2.0

Tags: authentication, react-native, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs

I'm trying to access a Microsoft Dynamics 2011 CRM deployment. My company has set up a ADFS test server for me and I am getting the following error. My client is written in react-native and uses Jason Lattimer's library which can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/jlattimer/bfeffb02d3efd159d0af
I believe the SOAP fault is being thrown by the getHeaderOnPremise function of his library.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Actions:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:
Action><a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:f1b5b2e8-b3bb-4c65-b533-
46dea29b5f66</a:RelatesTo></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code>
<s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-
1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason>
<s:Text xml:lang="en-US">ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated 
or authorized.</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I've googled everything I can regarding "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized" and am still stuck. Is it possible that because his library uses synchronous XMLHttpRequests, and I converted those to asynchronous, that this change causes this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: So it's not throwing error if it's synchronous?

Comment: Well react-native doesn't allow synchronous XMLHttpRequests so I haven't been able to try. It's synchronous in his library though, I'm not sure if it's absolutely needed. Do I need to do a promise here to simulate synchronicity in an async request?

Comment: Usually looking at ADFS error log as well as enabling tracing log can give you more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-how-to-enable-debug-tracing(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot Monday and hopefully find the cause of the issue.